# New work server accessing active directory

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

My Department recently bought a small server running windows server 2008. But given its a business managed server IT refuses to provid e me with any support. At the moment I can only create loc al users. However I need to create access so I can use my active directory account to remote access i nto the server. Do I need to firstly install Active Directory on the server?

Comment: `Do I need to firstly install Active Directory on the server?` - No, you need to join it to the existing AD domain.

Comment: So I would simply go to control panel and system and just change the domain to my workplace domain?

Comment: The most important question: why didn't your IT department ask you what your requirements were and give you a suitable platform for your needs?  Surely they don't want random departments joining self-bought servers to their AD.

Comment: Could you clarify your question - did your department buy a server without approval from the IT department and now you want to be able to use your Active Directory accounts on it?

Comment: When we bought the server, IT gave us 2 choices, an IT managed server or a business managed server. IT said they provide absolutely no support for business managed servers. That was their policy. Has nothing to do with approvals.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the privileges to do so, you would join the server to the domain.  You would basically replace the workgroup with the domain, yes.   Depending on how the domain is configured, you may or may not be allowed to do this.